# How do I embed a parameter into my website?

Tags: html

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="playlist=folderName/
 playlist.txt&amp;width=400&amp;height=150&amp;showvolume=1&amp;sliderwidth=10&amp;volumewidth=50&amp;volumeheight=10" /> 



///playlist.php  
http://www.mysite.com/folderName/mySong.mp3|Song Artist - Song Title
http://www.mysite.com/folderName/mySong2.mp3|Song Artist 2 - Song
Title 2
```

You may remember my exmaple from my question before of an mp3 player, this is the playlist parameters for the object. How do i emebed this into my sit, do I change something inside the player. Because it does not show.(yes i made playlist.txt with correct info.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should surround param with object tags..